# How to have a screen that lists multiple results, each of which is a clickable link (on Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm new to GUI's,
I made a basic search engine that finds documents that contain certain words and puts them in a list.

Now, I want this list of paths to be displayed on my GUI, one under the other (using `\n` I guess), all of them clickable and automatically opening the right document for you with something like:
`os.startfile(path, 'open')`

In the current version I am only displaying one result (the first in the list) and I'm doing it with a label as so:

```
my_label.config(text=path)
my_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: os.startfile(path, 'open'))
```

I could just make more labels but then it's inefficient and also not dynamic (the one I envision would list all results and be scrollable for example).

Appreciate any help in this.

Comment: I would recommend to consider `Treeview` for this task. Also a `for item in mylist:` loop should make this happen. In addition you could use the items/path and slice them, so you can get a identifying key that can be added to a global dictionary that will store all the information that you need within nested dictionaries.

Comment: You can use `Listbox`.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this: using `Listbox`, `Treeview`, `Canvas`, `Text`. I recommend you spend a bit more time trying to solve this yourself using any of those widgets. The `Listbox` is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set of `Label` and `bind` right click to it, or a single `Listbox` to show your paths and `bind` on it.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

lst = [f'path {i}' for i in range(1,6)]

def select(e):
    path = e.widget.get(*e.widget.curselection())
    os.startfile(path,'open')

lstbox = Listbox(root)
lstbox.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

for i in lst:
    lstbox.insert('end',i)

lstbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',select) # Or lstbox.bind('<Double-1>',select) for double click

root.mainloop()
```

`lst` is supposed to be replaced with your required list. Another viable approach is set of `Buttons` with `command` that opens the required path.